# MongoDB: Exclude fields that start with a typical string

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My Dataset looks like that:

```
{
"A_asdsd" : "1",
"A_fghf" : "1",
"B_tzzz" : "1",
"B_ghh" : "1",.... }
```

How do I have to specify my find() Function, that all fields that start with A_ are excluded? (There are thousand of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.4.

Create an an key value array using `$$ROOT` for document.

[`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter the keys and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to create document structure.

[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the document to top.

```
 db.col.aggregate([
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":
  {"$arrayToObject":{
   "$filter":{
    "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"},
    "cond":{"$not":{"$eq":[{"$substrBytes":["$$this.k", 0, 2]}, "A_"]}}
     }
   }}
}}])
```

Comment: Just curious. Did you get a chance to try my solution ?

Comment: I just tried it: db.getCollection('...').col.aggregate([...}}]) but I Fetched 0 records

Comment: What is your mongodb version ? Can you share the query that you have with one sample document ?

Comment: I am using MongoDB 3.4.10 this is my Query: db.getCollection('my_collection').col.aggregate([
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":
  {"$arrayToObject":{
   "$filter":{
    "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"},
    "cond":{"$not":{"$eq":[{"$substrBytes":["$$this.k", 0, 2]}, "Mp"]}}
     }
   }}
}}])

Comment: I am really sry, but I am not allowed to share my document :(

Comment: I noticed you have  `db.getCollection('my_collection').col.aggregate(...)` It should be `db.getCollection('my_collection').aggregate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't query based on field's name, only on their values.

Comment: thats really sad :(

Comment: I know... it could be really practical

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your suggestions.

Because I work with the data in python anyway, my solution is now to import the data in a data frame. With the following code line I could than exclude the fields:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('A_')]
```

df is my data frame